# checking if the elements of an array are present in another array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays

```
a = array([1,2,3])    
b = array([2,7])
```

Now I want to check if elements of a are in b
and the returning answer should be (False, True, False). Is there some simple way to do this without using functions?

Comment: This smells like homework, [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Where is that `array` function from? numpy?

Comment: Yes the array function is from numpy

Comment: I tried 1) a == b
        2) a == b.any()

Comment: Wow, you tried so much. Perhaps consulting a tutorial might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your generous advice

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
>>> numpy.setmember1d(a, b)
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

update, thanks seberg. With newer verions of numpy this is:

```
>>> numpy.in1d(a, b)
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: On newer numpy versions the function is called `np.in1d` (or `np.lib.arraysetops.in1d`, but the best solution with arrays, at least if `b` is not small.

Answer (score 2):

With standard python lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 7]
>>> tuple(x in b for x in a)
(False, True, False)
```

Assuming that your `array` function returns an object that also supports both iterations and the `in` operator, it should work the same.

Comment: This will be quite slow if a and b are large.

Comment: @BiRico All valid solutions, without knowing about numpy arrays, are that though :P

Comment: If b is large, I would probably opt for `[x in set(b) for x in a]` to avoid looping over b.

Comment: That will call `set(b)` `len(a)` times though. But yeah, obviously you could make changes to improve the performance.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, how about `b = set(b); tuple(x in b for x in a)`, does that work?

Answer (score 2):

Using only numpy:

```
>>> (a[:,None] == b).any(axis=-1)
```

(So, we transform `a` from a `(N,)` to a `(N,1)` array, then test for equality using numpy's broadcasting. We end up with a `(N, M)` array (assuming that `b` had a shape `(M,)`...), and we just check whether ther's a `True` on each row with `any(axis=-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I'd do it with lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 7]
>>> result = []
>>>
>>> for x in a:
...    result.append(x in b)
...
>>> print result
[False, True, False]
```

Comment: As other answers have shown this can be crushed down into a list or generator comprehension

Comment: I started typing my answer before there were any others. This answer may be unnecessarily verbose but it's still valid and could be of help to those who don't yet fully comprehend list comprehensions.